# Structure Map 2.6.1

Tags: c#, generics, structuremap

In my current project I'm currently trying to replace the Windsor IoC in favour of structure map (2.6.1). But having a bit of problem registering some generic types. How would I register `IFilterConverter<T>` to use `FilterConverter<SomeSpecificType>`. I've tried ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(IFilterConverter) but from what I've read ([Jimmy Bogard's article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/12/17/advanced-structuremap-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types.aspx)) I would need a concrete type defined like so:- `SomeConcreteType : IFilterConverter<SomeSpecificType>` for that to work and I don't have that.

So to reiterate if I have a type that takes a constructor argument `IFilterConverter<SomeSpecificType>`, I want structure map to provide me with `FilterConverter<SomeSpecificType>`.

With Windsor I was using the XML config option (which I want to get away from) But all I did was just set up the configuration like so:

```
<component id="IFilterConverter" service="SomeNamespace.IFilterConverter`1, SomeNamespace" type="SomeNamespace.FilterConverter`1, SomeNamespace" lifestyle="PerWebRequest">
```

How do I do the equivalent in SM (using code, not XML config files)

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity - why are you migrating from Windsor to StructureMap?

Comment: No major reason, just that I've heard and read a lot about structure map and wanted to give it a try. As I said in my OP I was using the config file option with Windsor and didn't care for it much. I do realise I could have just switched to configuring Windsor via c# code but thought I'd give SM a try. I'm in no way suggesting that SM is any way "better" than Windsor. It was just really curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
_container = new Container();
_container.Configure(x =>
                         {
                             x.For(typeof (IFilterConverter<>)).Use(typeof (FilterConverter<>));
                         });
```